# How to read XML header information using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am trying to figure out how to use Linq to XML to read an XML file into my C# program.  Here is the example for my question:

```
<node name="services" class="tridium.containers.ServiceContainer" module="coreRuntime" release="2.301.532.v1">
```

How do I access the name, class, module, and release information in this line?  I tried .element("node").Name for the name field, but that just returns "node".  All of the tutorials I can find are either too simplistic to deal with this, or deal with writing an XML file.  Please help.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387086.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387070.aspx Note that [`XElement.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the name of the **element**, not the attribute `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this :

```
XElement rootelement = XElement.Load(@"path_to_your_file") ;

var name = rootElement.Attribute("name").Value ; 
var classname = rootElement.Attribute("class").Value ; 
var module = rootElement.Attribute("module").Value ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted this.  It is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.  (now I see you accidentally put "XmlElement") Don't know why the jerk downvoted instead of simply editing.  I will accept this answer.   Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, there was no call to downvote a correct answer, but 5 seconds of  reading through the XElement class documentation could've spared you the 10 minutes of waiting for an answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it is probably because it is a code-only answer; most people prefer some additional explanation or maybe references to more information in answers.

Answer (score 0):

If it is at the root, then

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");

var name= xdoc.Root.Attribute("name").Value;
var class= xdoc.Root.Attribute("class").Value;
var module= xdoc.Root.Attribute("module").Value;
```